# > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have this error when I built flutter project :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
> > YOUR_HOST
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
> > YOUR_HOST
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
> > YOUR_HOST
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > YOUR_HOST
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > YOUR_HOST
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > YOUR_HOST

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BULD FAILED in 3s

> Exception: Gradle task assembly debug failed with exit code 1

Comment: check your internet connection

Answer (score 2):

This kind of issue usually appears either due to a gradle misconfig or in your case, it looks more of an internet issue.

Try running `flutter clean` in your project source and then using `flutter build appbundle` and check whether you're able to run the command without any errors.

In case, you're still facing any errors, go to `android/build.gradle` in your flutter project and edit this line

from `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'`

to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2`

Then repeat the above steps again with `flutter clean` and `flutter build appbundle`.
It should work.

Answer (score 1):

run Flutter upgrade first

```
flutter upgrade
```

then run flutter clean

```
flutter clean
```